# How to add a scrollbar to jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery

[image]Please visit [my page](http://210.94.200.250/ocw/view.php?id=1).

And if you click other tabs, you'll see what my problem is. The tab DIV will go over the line of my wrapper.
I tried to figure out if there's any option to add scroll or not, and there is not!

Also tried to set the height value to DIV of tab. But it didn't work.

What I want is to add a scoll IN the tab DIV.
so no matter how long the content of tab is, the Wrapper DIV stays the same.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This CSS rule should be enough:

```
#tabs {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set a css property `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` along with a height and you should get standard scrollbars being rendered on whichever div you want.

If you just want vertical scroll bars then use `overflow-y:auto`