# Activate scrollbar when element goes offscreen using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle, scrolltop

I am using jQuery to slideToggle a hidden div when a link is clicked, but this div is very large and the bottom half goes offscreen when appearing.  But I cannot get the scrollbar to activate so the user can scroll downward.

Here is my sample code:  http://jsfiddle.net/3fgzu/

Though it works here, it is because of jsfiddle.  On my website, I am trying to accomplish the same thing by something like:

```
    $('#toggle3').click(function(){
        $('#resume').slideToggle(1000);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top} + $('window').height()
    }, 2000);
        return false;
    });
```

I hope my question makes sense.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: ....maybe your element in your code is positioned absolutely?

Comment: @scooterlord Oh my gosh, yes.  I have everything in a container div, and it was set to a fixed position... though I had no idea that this would affect it.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

check this link... it might help you..

```
#tabs {
height:100%;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

from: [How to add a scrollbar to jQuery tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068473/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-jquery-tabs)